# Change the default emulator

Tags: android, virtual-machine

I have set the android studio's emulator as the default for running the app.... 
Now I want to use the genymotion  or my phone.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow this navigation;

> app -> Edit Configurations -> General -> Deployment Target Options ->
>   Target -> Open Select Deployment Target Dialog

Comment: Thanks got the directions

Comment: You are welcome @shubhammeher, if it worked for you, can you please mark my answer as accepted? Thanks!